# plot hexbin density over map with base graphics in R

Tags: r, spatial

I have spatial coordinate data, and I would like to plot a density map of these coordinates, overlaying a map. The hexbin R package looks promising, but I am struggling to figure out how to plot hexbin data over a map. I would also prefer to stick with base graphics, rather than ggplot.

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do (that doesn't work):

```
library(hexbin)
library(sf)
library(maps)

x <- rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = 40)
y <- rnorm(10000, mean = 0, sd = 20)

bin <- hexbin(x, y)

pts <- st_as_sf(cbind.data.frame(x,y), coords = 1:2, crs = "+init=epsg:4326")

map(col = gray(0.95), fill=T, lwd=0.2)

plot(pts, add=TRUE, pch = 3, cex=0.5)
```

[image]

Here, the hexbin data are not plotting in the coordinate space of the map.

```
map(col = gray(0.95), fill=T, lwd=0.2)
plot(bin, style = "colorscale", newpage=FALSE)
```

[image]

Any sugggestions? Thanks!